# Error while running model training in google cloud ml

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I want to run model training in the cloud. I am following [this link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/flowers-tutorial) which runs a sample code to train a model based on flower dataset. The tutorial consists of 4 stages:

1. Set up your Cloud Storage bucket
2. Preprocessing training and evaluation data in the cloud
3. Run model training in the cloud
4. Deploying and using the model for prediction

I was able to complete step 1 and 2, however in step 3, job is successfully submitted but somehow error occurs and task exits with non exit status 1. Here is the log of the task

[image: Error logs during model training]

Screenshot of expanded log is:

[image: Expanded error logs]

I used following command:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training test${JOB_ID} \
    --stream-logs \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --package-path trainer\ 
    --staging-bucket ${BUCKET_NAME} \
    --region us-central1 \
    --runtime-version=1.2 \
    -- \
    --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/training" \
    --eval_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval*" \
    --train_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/train*"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm that the input files (eval_data_paths and train_data_paths) are not empty? Additionally if you are still having issues can you please file an issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples since its easier to handle the issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and couldn't figure out, then I followed [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/object-detection-tensorflow-and-google-cloud-platform-72e0a3f3bdd6), do it again from `git clone` and there was no error after running on gcs.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from your error message

```
The replica worker 1 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination reason: Error
```

that you have some programming error (syntax, undefined etc).

For more information, Check the [return code and meaning](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/troubleshooting)

> Return code -------------Meaning-------------- Cloud ML Engine response
>
> 0    Successful completion      Shuts down and releases job resources.
>
> 1-128   Unrecoverable error      Ends the job and logs the error.

Your need to find your bug first and fix it, then try again.

I recommend run your task locally (if your configuration supports) before you submit in cloud. If you find any bug, you can fix easily in your local machine.

Comment: Yes Hafizur, you are right but just for you information I have solved this issue. The training script was running perfectly on my local system but I had to make minor changes into the script to make it run on the cloud platform.